# Use S3 bucket folders for Elastic Pipeline input bucket and output bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pipeline, amazon-elastic-transcoder

I am putting together an AWS Elastic Pipeline to transcode the video however I want the input the pipeline takes to be from a folder in an AWS S3 bucket and the output to be sent to a different folder in the same AWS S3 bucket.

I am not sure how to achieve this because the settings for setting up a pipeline strictly accept a bucket name and when I try to add a path it says it does not satisfy the regular expression pattern.

What can I do to fix this? or is it even possible?

Comment: Are you clicking in the UI? Are you running an CLI command? Where specifically does it only accept a bucket? Isn't there a different setting available to set a prefix somewhere?

Comment: I am using the UI but I'm not sure if different options are available if I were to use a different interface.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to achieve it like this:

1. When creating the pipeline select the same bucket for the **Input
   Bucket** and **Bucket**(the output bucket)
2. When creating a job you can choose an output folder: **Output Key Prefix**
3. The input object is selected by key, so you can choose a video in any folder
4. Enter a file name as Output Key and select Preset
5. Start the job

The output file should be created in the input bucket in the folder you specified.